# How to call a function on a custom type

Tags: go, go-templates

I've seen some similar questions but I can't find one that solves my problem.

I have a custom `Money` type that aliases int64 with a function that formats the value as a string:

```
type Money int64

func (m *Money) Format() string {
    abs := math.Abs(int64(*m))

    dollars := int64(abs) / 100
    cents := int64(abs) % 100

    sign := ""
    if *m < 0 {
        sign = "-"
    }

    return fmt.Sprintf("%s$%d.%0.2d", sign, dollars, cents)
}
```

I have a HTML template that I pass a data struct. The struct has a list of invoice items on it that each have a Money field, and another Money field that holds the total.

```
type InvoiceItem {
    // ...
    Cost money.Money
}

type data struct {
    Name      string
    Items     []*model.InvoiceItem
    StartDate time.Time
    EndDate   time.Time
    Total     money.Money
}
```

I pass the `data` to my template and execute it:

```
t := template.Must(template.New(title).Parse(templateString))
t.Execute(&buf, data)
```

In my template I range over the invoice items and call the `Format` function on the `Money` object. This works:

```
{{range .Items}}
<tr>
    <td>{{.Description}}</td>
    <td>{{.Cost.Format}}</td>
</tr>
{{end}}
```

Later on I attempt to print the total field:

```
<td><strong>{{ .Total.Format }}</strong></td>
```

My templates throws an error:

```
 ... executing "Invoice Items" at <.Total.Format>: can't evaluate field Format in type money.Money
```

Why is it that I can call `Format` on the `Money` field when I range over the list of invoice items, but I can't call it on the `data.Total` object? From the error message it seems that the template knows that the type of `Total` is `Money`, so what's the problem?

Comment: Make `Format` a method of `Money` instead of `*Money`.

Comment: Thanks @Volker, that was the problem. If you want to put this in an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like your `data` struct is unexported.
Do this:

```
type Data struct { 

}
```

Comment: It doesn't need to be exported as long as its fields/methods are (and they are).

Comment: The struct is local to the method it's used in, and I can already access the fields in the template.